# How to approximate a 3D shape to a grid?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, approximation

Given a 3D object, how do I convert it into an approximated shape in which all the sides of the object are parallel to either of the co-ordinate planes, and all the vertices have integer co-ordinates?
For example, a sphere with center at origin and a radius of 1.5 will be approximated to a cube with center at origin and side length of 2.
For another example, the line given by **x = y = 0.5** will have an approximated shape as a rectangular parallelepiped with infinite length, and width and breadth as 1, and positioned such that one of its edge is along z-axis, while all the faces are along or parallel to either of x-z or y-z co-ordinate planes.

I am working with finite objects only, the above example is only meant to explain my needs.
I want an algorithm which can do this for me for any shape.

Answer (score 2):

In general case you need to determine maximum and minimum shape coordinates along every axis and define minimum axis aligned integer bounding box with values [rounded to larger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer) (using Ceil)  for max and rounded to smaller (using Floor) for min coordinates. For example:

```
XMin_Box = Floor(XMin_Shape)
XMax_Box = Ceil(XMax_Shape)
```

Edit:

If you need to approximate a shape with more precision, consider some kind of [voxelization](http://labs.cs.sunysb.edu/labs/projects/volume/Papers/Voxel/) (3d analog of 2d rasterization)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was however not looking for that. I think I need to give a better example in my question.